# Can players choose when to retrieve power sources in Assassin's Creed 3?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Can players choose when to retrieve power sources in Assassin's Creed 3? Or do these events/missions only happen at specific times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the game will force you every time you have to get one.

But you can go and put them in their socket at anytime you want (after the related present mission). I didn't do it before they ASKED me to do it in the main game.

Comment: There are 2 more if I remember well. But don't worry, the game will prompt it to you when you'll have to go and find them. Also, don't worry that the acheivment icon has it like it is the 2nd present part. The acheivement with the icon for the 1st part is later in the game. They just didn't backcheck this I guess.